# How do I open & save a .ics calendar file from Salesforce via email directly to Outlook (or others)?

Tags: calendar, outlook, files

I have an HTML email that I need to send to contacts with an option to book a calendar event directly from the email. I created the event in Outlook, saved it as a .ics file which I then uploaded into Salesforce as an externally available document.

The link in the HTML email looks like this:

```
<a href="https://ap1.salesforce.com/sfc/p/90000000tgIp/a/900000000miy/5gbeq919z3J_sbrdrV_SgcRbY13CgY" target="_blank" title="Save to Outlook">
    <img align="none" height="58" src="https://ap1.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?oid=00D90000000tgIp&id=0159000000CZWzZ" style="width: 166px; height: 58px; margin: 0px;" alt="Save to Outlook" width="166"></a>
```

When the link is clicked on the email though, it opens a webpage that looks like this. The contact then has to click on the 'download' button and open it, then save it manually to the calendar.

[image]

I would like them to be able to click on the link and for it to open the file automatically and add it to the calendar. What do I need to do to achieve this?